# LinearLayout gravity inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

Hey I'm making a simple chat application. I'm having these two layouts to pass for the inflater to add to the RecyclerView:

**received_msg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#f00">

<TextView
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**sent_msg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_gravity="right">

<TextView
    android:text="Text"
    android:textColor="#f00"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

The **layout_gravity** property seem to have no effect on the **sent_msg.xml**'s LinearLayout. What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the two item XML's full width (`match_parent`) and move the `layout_gravity` and `background` attributes to the child TextView:

**sent_msg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"                  (* Changed)
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:text="Text"
    android:background="#fff"                            (* Changed)
    android:textColor="#f00"
    android:layout_gravity="right"                       (* Changed)
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```